# Inner product given by its orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Say we have an inner product such that $\{(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,1,1)\}$ is an orthonormal basis. I'm asked to find

1. $||(1,2,3)||$
2. An orthonormal basis for $U=$span$\{(0,1,0),(0,0,2)\}$
3. The orthonormal projection of $v=(3,2,1)$ on $U$.

Now approaching this problem, I calculated 1 using the following method:
We can write $(1,2,3)$ as $-1(1,0,0)-1(1,1,0)+3(1,1,1)$.
We also know that for orthonormal basis, we can also write:
$(1,2,3)=\langle(1,2,3),(1,0,0)\rangle(1,0,0)+\langle(1,2,3),(1,1,0)\rangle(1,1,0)+\langle(1,2,3),(1,1,1)\rangle(1,1,1)$

So we can infer the inner product of $\langle(1,2,3),(1,0,0)\rangle=1, \langle(1,2,3),(1,1,0)\rangle=1, \langle(1,2,3),(1,1,1)\rangle=3$

Using linearity of inner product we can then infer:
$||(1,2,3)||^2=\langle(1,2,3),(1,2,3)\rangle=-1\langle(1,2,3),(1,0,0)\rangle-1\langle(1,2,3),(1,1,0)\rangle+3\langle(1,2,3),(1,1,1)\rangle=11$

Using the same approach I found that the orthonormal basis of $U$ is $B=\{\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(0,1,0),\frac{1}{\sqrt8}(0,1,2)\}$.

First of all - is my approach right? And secondly I'm having trouble with finding the projection, for some reason it always comes out $(0,0,0)$ which feels pretty weird to me.

Comment: Your approach for part 1 is fine. It's not clear what you did for part 2 since I don't see how the "same approach" applies.

Comment: Also, the answer $(0,0,0)$ is correct for part 3

Comment: We have Gram - Schmidt process for finding orthnormal basis given a basis of a vector space. It requires similar calculations - meaning I used the same idea for finding the inner product of other vectors that are used in the Gram - Schmidt process.

Comment: You could save some work if you use the fact that
$$
\langle a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2 + a_3 v_3, b_1 v_1 + b_2 v_2 + b_3 v_3\rangle = 
a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + a_3 b_3,
$$
where $v_1 = (1,0,0), v_2 = (1,1,0), v_3 = (1,1,1)$. For example: in part 1, once you have $v = -1\cdot v_1 -1\cdot v_2 + 3\cdot v_3$, you can immediately deduce that $\|v\|^2 = (-1)^2 + (-1)^2 + 3^2$.

Comment: How did you determine that?

Comment: To verify the formula I give, use the fact that the $v_i$ are orthonormal and expand the inner product linearly.